# Double call on .change() method when there are not breakpoints/debuggers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, dom-events

I have a `.change()` event for some inputs and an AJAX call. When I change the value of the input the AJAX method is called twice and `.change()` event is triggered twice. But when I put a 'debugger;' or a breakpoint in the file it is called only once.

I have logged the event variable and for the first call the .isTrigger is not present but for the second call it is assigned a value of 3.
I fail to trace where the second call/trigger is coming from. Anyone have any idea?

```
$('#inputField').change(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // first call e.isTrigger is 'undefined'
    // second call e.isTrigger is '3'
});
```

What I did to prevent the second call is this:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'inputField' && typeof(e.isTrigger) != 'undefined') {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   return;
}
```

But I think of it more as a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: I saw this question and then checked my code for a duplicate input with the same ID - there was none.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] that shows your issue then.

Comment: The field is a bootstrap datimepicker Time input.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a problem with the selector. For select tags, some plugins create dummy select input and a div so try this

```html
$('select#inputField').on('change', function(){

}
```

Also, check for multiple jquery files or update jquery version if that works.